# Colorize running log after marker

Tags: perl, sed

Often I need to analyze large logs in console.
I use the following command to colorize important keywords:

`echo "string1\nerror\nsuccess\nstring2\nfail" | perl -p -e 's/(success)/\e[1;32;10m$&\e[0m/g;' -e 's/(error|fail)/\e[0;31;10m$&\e[0m/g'`

It will colorize "success" with green, and error messages with red and keeps others lines unchanged (as they contain some useful info).
But in some cases I need to colorize values after some marker, but not marker itself, i.e. in these lines

```
Marker1: value1
Marker2: value2
```

need to highlight only value1 and value2 by known markers.
I'm looking for a way to modify my current oneliner to add this function

Also I tried the following solution, which I like less

```
#!/bin/bash

default=$(tput op)
red=$(tput setaf 1 || tput AF 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2 || tput AF 2)

sed -u -r "s/(Marker1: )(.+)$/\1${red}\2${default}/
    s/(Marker2: )(.+)$/\1${green}\2${default}/" "${@}"`
```

But it has some problem with buffering, so it's ok for some constant file, but log which is continuosly running is not displayed at all

UPDATE:
Found a solution with help of some perl guru.

```
echo -e "string1\nerror\nsuccess\nstring2\nfail\nMaker1: value1\nMaker2: value2" | \
perl -p \
-e 's/(success)/\e[32m$&\e[0m/g;' \
-e 's/(error|fail)/\e[31m$&\e[0m/g;' \
-e 's/(Maker1:) (.*)/$1 \e[36m$2\e[0m/m;' \
-e 's/(Maker2:) (.*)/$1 \e[01;34m$2\e[0m/m;'
```

Comment: If that edit is an answer you should post it as such and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

default=$(tput op)
red=$(tput setaf 1 || tput AF 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2 || tput AF 2)
#default='e[0m'
#red='e[0;31;10m'
#green='e[1;32;10m'

# automaticaly use passed argument file if any or stdin if not
sed -u -r \
 "/success/    s//${green}&${default}/
  /error|fail/ s//${red}&${default}/
  /^Marker1:/ {s//\1${red}/;s/$/${default}/;}
  /^Marker2:/ {s//\1${green}/;s/$/${default}/;}" \
    $( [ ${#@} -gt 0 ] && echo ${@} )
```

For a one line:

- remove other line thans sed one
- replace newline in sed by `;`
- use directly the terminal code in place of variable
- remove the last line if you pipe or use specific file instead

Comment: I have already posted perl solution, but let's accept it as alternative sed solution (I tested and it works)

Comment: could be usefull for other to have a test result (in time for example) for both solution

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "string1\nerror\nsuccess\nstring2\nfail\nMaker1: value1\nMaker2: value2" | \
perl -p \
-e 's/(success)/\e[32m$&\e[0m/g;' \
-e 's/(error|fail)/\e[31m$&\e[0m/g;' \
-e 's/(Maker1:) (.*)/$1 \e[36m$2\e[0m/m;' \
-e 's/(Maker2:) (.*)/$1 \e[01;34m$2\e[0m/m;'
```